# Why powershell does not run Angular commands?

Tags: javascript, angular, powershell, angular-cli

I have started to learn Angular but I note that powershell in Windows gives me an error whenever I make an angular command like:

```
ng new new-app
```

or

```
ng serve
```

this is the error what I got:

```
ng : File C:\Users\< username >\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng.ps1 cannot be loaded because 
running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see 
about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1
+ ng serve
+ ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

P.S. I try these commands in cmd and it works.

Comment: Can you run `Get-ExecutionPolicy` and provide the output? Additionally can you run to `C:\Users\< username >\AppData\Roaming\npm` and open the properties for `ng.ps1`, to see if there is a tick box which states "blocked", if so untick this.

Comment: I think the best way is removing ng.ps1 when I did everything has worked again

Comment: @TheFabio Actually May I will never know, after deleting ng.ps1 everything was going in perfect way.

Comment: My Execution policy was not the issue but how I sent the arguments. If you are in the same boat, check out [Executing Angular Serve From Powershell With Parameters Fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67973375/executing-angular-serve-from-powershell-with-parameters-fail?noredirect=1#comment120143363_67973375)

Comment: @AmirMakram Sir, this question is not related to `javascript` language, so please don't add the `javascript` tag.

Answer (score 882, accepted):

Remove `ng.ps1` from the directory `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\npm\` then try clearing the npm cache at `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\`

Comment: FYI clearing the cache was not necessary for me.

Comment: Great, but why? Is it left over from a previous Angular installation and no longer being called correctly? Why does it no longer work?

Comment: Actually, I don't know.
I don't even found any mention for this file anywhere so I thought that file really not necessary, so I just delete it

Comment: I have the "ng.ps1" (and "ng.cmd" and "ng", and "node_modules" folder) in C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\npm  folder. They were (re)created 2 days ago when I run ng update (I checked the modified date). After that update (current 8.3.21, previous: 8.3.xx) the ng stop to work with Powershell. Deleting it (renamed) solved the problem. No cache cleaning is needed but in VS Code you need to kill and reopen the Terminal. Maybe Angular introduced the "ng" command directly as a powershell script-let but that resulted in this common permission problem ?!

Comment: You don't need to do this - see the answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/58710158/834431

Comment: If you have ERROR 'More than one module matches. Use skip-import option to skip importing the component into the closest module.', please use `ng g c new-component --module app`

Good Luck

Comment: Just clearing the cache worked for me lol.

Comment: In my case it ng.ps1 was not residing in C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\npm\ instead it was in C:\Program Files\nodejs\ng.ps1.  Removing this helped me to resolve the issue. 

I use NVM to support multiple version on Node.

Comment: For anybody who wonders why this works: Windows by default blocks running unsigned powershell scripts because of security concerns. What is weird is why angular team keeps that script while it's really default behaviour for it to break Angular CLI and systems with unsigned script execution enabled are a minority. 
Removing this powershell script just stops Powershell from trying to execute .ps1 file and fall back to old cmd script, that also works, but was never restricted by Microsoft.

Answer (score 665):

I solved my problem by running below command

`Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser`

Comment: for more infor ... http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170

Comment: This should be the correct answer for new installs.

Comment: This seems to be right but quite unreliable.

Comment: after this comment i enter 'a' to apply to All Policies. Thank You!

Comment: I have executed the same in my machine. It worked.Thanks a lot for sharing this.

Comment: This fails in some enterprise environments where we are unable to set these perms.

Comment: Yes i have resolved the issue by using this command set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser

Comment: Use this to check "Get-ExecutionPolicy"

Comment: This today even saved my day, thanks

Answer (score 41):

> script1.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on
>   this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170

This error happens due to a security measure which won't let scripts be executed on your system without you having approved of it. You can do so by opening up a powershell with administrative rights (search for powershell in the main menu and select Run as administrator from the context menu) and entering:

```
set-executionpolicy remotesigned
```

Comment: Why do I specifically need to do this, when other folks does not have the same issue than me with the same version?

Answer (score 12):

**Step 1**

First, you have to need to open the command prompt and run this command.

`set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser`

**Step 2**

Now you have to run the second command on your system. This command is:

`Get-ExecutionPolicy`

**Step 3**

To view their policy, you need to run this command in your command prompt:

`Get-ExecutionPolicy -list`

> https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-fix-ps1-can-not-be-loaded-because-running-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-sys/

Answer (score 4):

This error happens due to a security measure that won't let scripts be executed on your system without you having approved it.

Solution:-

1. Open Windows PowerShell
2. execute this command

   set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser

Answer (score 3):

Step1: Get-ExecutionPolicy for your Machine using the below command

```
Get-ExecutionPolicy -List
```

Step2: Once your identity scope and execution policy, please run the below commands using the same.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
```

if above doesn't work, install the minimum node version angular required and run bellow command

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

if you want handle multiple node version use nvm as follows;

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/node-version-manager-nvm-install-guide/

Comment: It is worth remembering that after applying the command, the operation of the 'ng' command was immediate, I didn't even need to raise the application's permissions (VSCode) as an administrator.

Answer (score 1):

This error happens due to a security measure that won't let scripts be executed on your system without you having approved it.

I've also solved my problem by executing this command: **Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser**

This video helped me to fix this issue: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a--z7ZV1BqM

You can also try this. Hopefully will resolve your issue as well.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser`.

Important things to note when running this command:

1. run `ng` from project folder
2. check `ng` version
3. check `angular cli` in properly install or you can reinstall by running `npm install -g @angular/cli`

Answer (score -5):

open windows powershell, run as administrater and SetExecution policy as Unrestricted then it will work.

Comment: Welcome to SO, complete your answer by providing the commands that do the works

Comment: This is a pretty bad advice as it opens the door to run any PowerShell script on your system.

Comment: As stated in a previous answer ```Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser``` is a better way to go as it is less prone to open your system to running a malicious script. 

RemoteSigned
1) The script has to be signed by a trusted publisher. 
2) The scope is set to the current user instead of the default which is LocalMachine. 

See Microsoft's documentation for additional details. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-7.1