# Executing Angular Serve From Powershell With Parameters Fail

Tags: powershell, angular-cli

I am attempting to run an angular server on a specific port launched from a Powershell script and **angular** reports configuration failure.

```
 & 'ng' @('serve', '--port', '5200')
```

> The specified command ("serve --port 5200") is invalid. For a list of
> available options, run "ng help".
>
> Did you mean "serve"?

Whereas without a port it works

```
& 'ng' 'serve'
```

---

I have tried `& 'ng' 'serve --port 5200'` and `& 'ng' @('serve', '--port 5200')` and it gets the same error message.

How does one resolve this or work around when attempting to execute `ng serve` with arguments from a script?

Comment: Don't group the arguments together like that: `& ng serve '--port' 5200` should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the arguments to `ng` as individual tokens (don't wrap the list in `@(...)`):

```
& ng serve '--port' 5200
```

Comment: That's definitely the best way to do it (as an aside: the quoting around `--port` is optional), but it's worth noting that the _first_ command in the question works too: -- `& 'ng' @('serve', '--port', '5200')` (or just `& 'ng' ('serve', '--port', '5200')`) - given that an array's elements are passed as individual arguments to external programs.