# WebStorm ng.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system

Tags: angular, angularjs, powershell, visual-studio-code, webstorm

I had an error:

> ng : File `....\node_modules\.bin\ng.ps1` cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
> At line:1 char:1

Working with Angular in WebStorm, and this simple command has helped me:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
```

If anyone knows what this command does, I would appreciate it. I would like to learn a little more, what was the problem and why this command that I found on the Internet has helped me.

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/7296835/stanley-mohlala for the command.

No ng command worked.

```
ng generate component xxxxx
```

neither

```
ng g component xxxx
```

neither

```
ng g c xxxx
```

I couldn't see the Angular version either, I got an error.

```
ng version
```

The error :

> ng : File `C:\www\angular004560\node_modules\.bin\ng.ps1` cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

This error occurs when running `ng` commands in Windows PowerShell as Windows by default blocks running unsigned powershell scripts because of security concerns, thus the issue. And WebStorm uses the `powershell.exe` as its default terminal.

You can change the default shell to `cmd.exe` in **Settings | Tools | Terminal, Shell path...**, or run `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser` in PowerShell to overcome the issue.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-7.3 for information about execution policies. See also the answers in [Why powershell does not run Angular commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58032631/why-powershell-does-not-run-angular-commands)